# How to convert boost multiarray to numpy array c++

Tags: c++, numpy, boost, boost-python

I have a `boost::multiarray` (`boost::multi_array_ref<uint_pixel_type,9>`). How can i convert it to numpy array without losing the dimensions using

`numpy/ndarrayobject.h`

and return it to python in c++?

```
boost::multi_array_ref<uint_pixel_type,9>
```

to ndarrayobject

Comment: Improve grammar, highlight code, remove C++ version-specific tag